# Calculating dates in Javascript returns NaN-NaN-NaN

Tags: javascript, datetime

I'm currently working a small application which incorporates a date calculation in javascript. It consists of 3 form elements. The first element lets a user specify the number of nights he would like to stay. The second element specifies the start date and the third element specifies the end date. Once the user chooses the staying length, the amount of nights should be added to the start date.

This is what I've come up with in Javascript for the "end_date" calculation:

```
function setExpDate(formDate){
// set number of days to add
var daystoadd2 = getStayingLength();
var startDate = new Date(formDate);

var expDate = startDate;
expDate.setDate(startDate.getDate() + daystoadd2);


var totaldate = expDate;
var curr_date = expDate.getDate();
var curr_month = expDate.getMonth() +1;
var curr_year = expDate.getFullYear();
var totaldate = (curr_date + "-" + curr_month + "-" + curr_year);

document.getElementById('end_Date').value = totaldate;};
```

This function is triggered with the onBlur event on the start_date field. This results in NaN-NaN-NaN. How should I change my code to make this work?

You can find the "app" here: [Form Calculation](http://www.professional-magento.nl/stay_calculation/calculate_booking.html)

Comment: Can we see the exact value passed in as formdate?

Comment: Check for errors in the browser console.

Comment: Either you're passing an invalid date, or `getStayingLength` doesn't return what you think it does

Comment: I can see that the getStayingLength value is correct. This value is retrieved from an array that returns the number of nights. For example a week: length_days["week"]=7; To make things more interesting I do get a date returned once in a while. Startdate 19-12-2013 with 7 nights returns 19-10-2013. My guess it should have something to do with how the date is being formatted. Using the datepicker there is no problem. Once the onBlur event kicks in it gets messed up.

Comment: If you are sure that `getStayingLength()` is working correctly that you have bad input format. Put  `console.log('formDate: ' + formDate);` in function `setExpDate()` to see what you get. If the string passed into `Date()` doesn’t represent a date, then it returns NaN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function setDate() worked with the following formats (because that is how Date() works):

```
setExpDate('11/29/2013');
setExpDate('November 29, 2013');
setExpDate('2013-11-29');
setExpDate('Friday November 29 2013');
```

If you want to use some other format as input, like `19-12-2013` then you have to change it before calling `Date()`. One possible way:

```
var dateParts = formDate.split('-');
formDate = dateParts[1] + '/' + dateParts[0] + '/' + dateParts[2];
var startDate = new Date(formDate);
```

Comment: Hi Anto, I tried what you've suggested I and do see some improvement but not entirely. Could you have a look at this: http://www.professional-magento.nl/stay_calculation/calculate_booking.html) and see if I'm missing something here? If you choose a length of stay and a start date, initially you get NaN-... Do it again and try choosing a startdate + 1 sequentialy.

Comment: You handle 'onblur` event and it seems that you do not get it the first time. And also later if you want to change date, after selection you have to do mouse down to input field and blur away and it works. Try with some other event. With `onchange` works better

Comment: When user select value from drop-down list `calculateTotal()` is called. Here you can check if date is already selected and calculate new end date.

Comment: Anto, the application is definately working as expected. Selection of date + the number of days returns the right end date. However, I've tested in Chrome and all works well. I've tried it in Safari and Firefox and both return NaN-... Should I add code that makes this correctly interpretted in these browsers?

Comment: I tried it with latest Firefox and IE10 and it is working like at Chrome with those changes. I did not change anything else. Try to debug it with some console.log() messages to see what data you are getting in.

Comment: That is quiet strange. I have logged the messages and all is well in Chrome. In FF (latest version) it keeps returning NaN values. I did some more research and I guess the date format dd-mm-yyyy is supported in Chrome and IE but not in FF or Safari. How to solve this?

Comment: You have currently in your code `formDate = dateParts[1] + '-' + dateParts[0] + '-' + dateParts[2];` Those `-` should be `/`

Comment: That did the trick. Don't forget to change the formDate.split. Thanks!